# app working on emualtor but not on device

Tags: android

hii I m new to android so please help me out with this.
I have made an application which connects to the server via DeafultHttpClient method, it works fine on the android gingerbread emulator but crashes when installed on the android gingerbread phones. have tried the USB debugging, logcat shows that cannot connect to server url.
have been stuck on this for quite sometime now.
would really appreciate for your help.

thanks in advance

Comment: Show us the logcat and show us the code where it is thrown. Telling us that you know the error message doesn't help us to help you.

Comment: probably your device has lost internet connection. You might have got socket exception (something like that) or unknownhost exception.. please post the stacktrace of exception along with logcat and code snippet

Answer (score 2):

The **emulator** use your computer connection to access the network, and so **has access to everything** your computer has.

The **phone might not**, depending if you are using Wifi, and if your network administrator allow connection to your server through wifi.

Check that your server is accessible from the outside (or through your wifi if your app won't be used outside)